Почему начало предложения принято писать с большой буквы?
Каждый считает долгом исправить меня, если я пишу с маленькой буквы в начале предложения. Почему так? Для поддержания общих правил написания любого текста? Разве нельзя использовать строчные буквы для некой эстетики?

Вопрос скорее психологического характера, нежели языковедческого. Почему люди ходят в дверь а не в окно? Почему ходят по тротуарам, а не по газонам? Почему ходят в обуви, а не босиком? Почему, если я иду босиком, все говорят мне одеть ботинки, хотя босиком походка более эстетичная? - Нет, не все, просто те кому всё равно или кто тоже считает это эстетичным чаще молчат.

ЭСТЕТИКА [тэ], -и; ж. [от греч. aisthētikós - чувствующий, чувственный]. 1. Философское учение о сущности и формах прекрасного в искусстве, в природе и в жизни. Курс по эстетике. Э. живописи. 2. Система чьих-л. или каких-л. взглядов на искусство. Э. Пушкина. Э. хорового пения. Музыкальная э. Э. реализма. 3. Красота, художественность в чём-л.; дизайн (2 зн.). Э. одежды. Э. быта. Техническая э.  ПРАВИЛА: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81

Какую именно эстетику вы хотите выразить с помощью строчной буквы? Красоту, художественность вашей речи? А в чем именно здесь можно увидеть нечто красочное и особенное. Пользователи этого не понимают и видят только нарушение правил. Конфликт, да?)) Так в чем же красота?  // Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос, а также ответить на него, если хотите что-нибудь добавить.

@Sharon я не думаю, что буквы что-то говорят именно о речи... к сожалению, да, пользователи уже полностью правили 1 мой вопрос вдоль и поперек, поэтому следующие вопросы я пишу уже с большими буквами...

Человек чуть ли не с рождения ценит себя как личность и не хочет быть похожим на других,  неотличимым среди себе подобных. И пока он не осознал свою индивидуальность, он опасается раствориться в окружающем мире, где так много всяких условностей. Это то, что можно назвать протестом юного поколения. Тот, кто не научился создавать, тот стремится разрушить.
Особая эстетика? Но стоит ли нарушать законы общей гармонии ради чего-то особенного? Негармоничные созвучия, нарушение симметрии  вызывают чувство дискомфорта, и только порядок всегда эстетичен и противопоставлен хаосу. Поэтому стоит задуматься о том, как создавались законы письма относительно прописных и строчных букв.
Вопрос дискуссионный))
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Из истории прописных и строчных букв
В современном русском языке буквы делятся на  прописные и строчные. Примечание. Не во всех языках существует такое разделение. Например, его нет в еврейском, арабском, корейском языках.

Правила написания заглавных и строчных букв складывались на протяжении многих веков. В первом русском алфавите — глаголице — не было такого разделения. Но уже в ранних образцах древнерусской кириллической письменности присутствуют буквы, по размеру значительно превосходящие другие. По форме написания все буквы в то время напоминали прописные. Но среди них выделялись инициалы или буквицы.

Древней Руси не существовало деления текста на предложения, но были буквицы, украшавшие начало текста. Пример — Остромирово Евангелие, XI век. Инициалы красиво прописывали и украшали витиеватыми рисунками. По размеру они были значительно больше современных заглавных букв русского языка.

После введения книгопечатания в XVI веке прописные буквы стали ставить в начале предложений, но далеко не всегда. Окончательно утвердилось деление на строчные и прописные буквы с введением Петром I гражданского шрифта в первой половине XVIII века.



  Некий Иван ударил колесом Наталью. Некая Наталья ударила 
  намордником Семена. Некий Семен ударил корытом Селифана... 

ТЕМА: Чем объясняется правило начала предложения с заглавной буквы? логически!  (Ответы Mail.ru)
ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ — это интонационно и грамматически оформленная единица речи (общения, коммуникации), которая служит средством формирования и выражения мысли.
Предложение может состоять из одного слова: Стучат! Однако слово как единица языка служит для называния предметов и явлений, а предложение как единица речи — для передачи информации.
Предложение отличается от слова также тем, что не воспроизводится и не хранится в памяти носителей языка в готовом виде, а создается, строится по определенным моделям, схемам.
От словосочетания (которое тоже строится по схемам) предложение отличается функцией (у словосочетания номинативная функция, у предложения — коммуникативная).
ДИАЛОГИ ПО ТЕМЕ
— Это просто правило в котором нет логики.
— Ускоряет быстрый анализ текста. Одно предложение — одна мысль. Понял, что это не та мысль, не дочитал и переходишь к другой.
— А каким правилом пользовался Создатель, создавая небо голубым? Видимо таким же...
— Если верить Кириллу с Мефодием, родоначальникам русской письменности, то каждую новую мысль нужно оформлять на бумаге именно с заглавной буквы. Потому что этим приёмом пользовались греческие писари, письмо которых и легло в основу русской письменности...
— Я ж НЕ про историю хотел бы... а про логическое объяснение!..
— Кирилл при создании кириллицы рассуждал ЛОГИЧЕСКИ. Раз греки так пишут — и мы так писать будем...
— Это НЕ логика, а подражание!
— А где логика, что небо голубое? Захотелось так, сказал — да будет так, и стало так...
— Вон в немецком все существительные с заглавной пишутся. Где логика?
— Вот тока не надо кивать на соседей, типа "они дураки, давайте и мы дураками будем!"...
— Я вам разрешаю на соседей кивать.
— а я Вам запрещаю!
— У Вас, батенька, логический диссонанс наблюдается...
— что-то я не могу определить какое у Вас расстройство — то оскорбить желаете, то льстить...
— А, так вы сюда пришли оскорбиться или обольститься?
— я пришёл сюда наблюдать!
— Наблюдают не вмешиваясь...
— а я активный наблюдатель. Провоцирующий.
— Значит все-таки оскорбиться пришел...

я не думаю, что именно в Интернете стоит править человека за то, что он пишет в начале предложения с маленькой буквы. было бы странностью писать какие-либо тексты, применяя только строчные буквы, я в этом соглашусь. не знаю, откуда возникла сама тенденция маленьких букв (да, это уже как тенденция), но понимаю, что выглядит вполне красивым, когда каждая буква одинакова по размеру. да, это действительно делает текст менее официальным, но о какой официальности может идти речь в интернете?)

Да пишите как хотите, но не забывайте, что вас читают разные люди. Если люди вас не знают, то они могут начать к вам применять те же правила поведения, которые требуют от себя. Если же они вас знают достаточно близко, то могут лучше воспринимать ваше самовыражение. Вообще, скорее всего потому что мозг ленив, и хочет, чтобы всё было "правильно", а правильно начинать предложение с большой буквы. А если неправильно пишешь или делаешь - это вызывает сильный стресс у людей ленивых ментально, который они тут же превращают в агрессию. Бегает мальчик, а старушка его палкой - не бегай!

Вы же себе придумали тоже по сути правило и его соблюдаете: о какой официальности может идти речь в интернете. Вас раздражает их какое-то проявление "правильности", ну и пошло-поехало:

Некий Иван ударил колесом Наталью.
Некая Наталья ударила намордником Семена.
Некий Семен ударил корытом Селифана.
Некий Селифан ударил поддевкой Никиту.
Некий Никита ударил доской Романа.
Некий Роман ударил лопатой Татьяну.
Некая Татьяна ударила кувшином Елену.
И началась драка.
Елена била Татьяну забором.
Татьяна била Романа матрацем.
Роман бил Никиту чемоданом.
Никита бил Селифана подносом.
Селифан бил Семена руками.
Семен плевал Наталье в уши.
Наталья кусала Ивана за палец.
Иван лягал Пантелея пяткой.

Эх,— думали мы,— дерутся хорошие люди.

А чем всё кончилось? И еще у  басни должна быть мораль.  Напишите, пожалуйста.  А почему они друг друга не били?   И ходили как:  босиком или в ботинках, в окно или в дверь?))  Кстати подростки мелких не любят — бегают, мешаются под ногами.

А вы комментарии иногда со строчной пишете или нет? В чем тут ваша эстетика?

@Sharon это Хармс, этим и кончилось.

Симпатичный...  https://dzen.ru/a/XOEfF2ZJAwC0Rlu0   Не успел дописать?

У него все такое, коротенькое.

@Sharon а комментарии никто еще и не правил) вопросы правят, на ответы/комментарии не лезут особо...
